# Jquery: changing certain class on mouseover of another element

Tags: jquery, class, mouseover, closest

Ok I have this piece of html, it appears a few times on the page it is always structurally the same but the links and link text will be different each time along with the list text.

```
<ul>
<li class="n1">Understand key issues relating to creating animations for interactive media products</li>
<li class="n2">Understand key contextual information relating to creating 2D animations for interactive media products</li>
<li class="n3">Be able to create 2D animations for use as part of an interactive media product</li>
<li class="n4">Be able to liaise with relevant parties</li>
<li class="n5">Be able to store 2D animations for use as part of an interactive media product</li>
</ul>
<hr />
<a href="alcohol_calculator.php" class="swfselector">
&raquo; Alcohol unit calculator prototype <img class="tab" src="/images/1.png" width="30" height="28" alt="1" /> <img class="tab" src="/images/2.png" width="30" height="28" alt="2" /><img class="tab" src="/images/3.png" width="30" height="28" alt="3" /> <img class="tab" src="/images/5.png" width="30" height="28" alt="5" />
</a>
<a href="bouncing_ball.php" class="swfselector">
&raquo; Bouncing ball animation <img class="tab" src="/images/3.png" width="30" height="28" alt="3" />
</a>
<a href="FOCC_mnemonic.php" class="swfselector">
&raquo; FOCC mnemonic <img class="tab" src="/images/1.png" width="30" height="28" alt="1" /> <img class="tab" src="/images/2.png" width="30" height="28" alt="2" /> <img class="tab" src="/images/3.png" width="30" height="28" alt="3" /> <img class="tab" src="/images/5.png" width="30" height="28" alt="5" />
</a>
<a href="information_literacy_quiz.php" class="swfselector">
&raquo; Information literacy quiz <img class="tab" src="/images/1.png" width="30" height="28" alt="1" /> <img class="tab" src="/images/2.png" width="30" height="28" alt="2" /> <img class="tab" src="/images/3.png" width="30" height="28" alt="3" /> <img class="tab" src="/images/5.png" width="30" height="28" alt="5" />
</a>
<a href="traffic_lights.php" class="swfselector">
&raquo; Traffic lights <img class="tab" src="/images/1.png" width="30" height="28" alt="1" /> <img class="tab" src="/images/2.png" width="30" height="28" alt="2" /> <img class="tab" src="/images/3.png" width="30" height="28" alt="3" /> <img class="tab" src="/images/5.png" width="30" height="28" alt="5" />
</a>
```

I am using this piece of Jquery to change the images in each swfselector link when they are mousedover:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.swfselector').find('.tab').each(function() {
                $(this).attr("src", 
                $(this).attr("src").replace(".png", "o.png"));  
             })  
});
$('.swfselector').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
  if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
            $(this).find('.tab').each(function() {
                $(this).attr("src", 
                $(this).attr("src").replace("o.png", ".png"));  

             })
   } else {
             $(this).find('.tab').each(function() {
                $(this).attr("src", 
                $(this).attr("src").replace(".png", "o.png"));  
             })
         }
    });
```

This all works so far... but now I have this piece of Jquery which attempts to also change the class of the corresponding

element above. So if someone hovers over an swf selector containing the images: 1.png, 3.png and 5.png. The list elements with classes: n1, n2 and n3 would change to: n1o n3o and n5o.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.swfselector').find('.tab').each(function() {
                $(this).attr("src", 
                $(this).attr("src").replace(".png", "o.png"));  
             })  
});
$('.swfselector').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
  if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
            $(this).find('.tab').each(function() {
                $(this).attr("src", 
            $(this).attr("src").replace("o.png", ".png"));  
            var srcString =  $(this).attr("src").substr(0, $(this).attr("src").length - 4);
            nameString =  srcString.substr(8, srcString.length - 1);
            $(this).closest('ul').find('li').each(function() {
            var className = $(this).attr('class');
              if (nameString.indexOf(className)) {
                  $(this).removeClass(className).addClass(className + 'o');
                  }
                })
             })
   } else {
             $(this).find('.tab').each(function() {
                $(this).attr("src", 
                $(this).attr("src").replace(".png", "o.png"));  
             })
         }
    });
```

The above code returns no errors, but does not do what I want ether.

Comment: Where does it go wrong? Just alert the data until it goes wrong..

Comment: `$(this).closest('ul').find('li').each(function() {`
It doesn't know what "this" is after here. Also srcString wasn't right as I forgot to remove the images/ path so I made a new substring called nameString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(this).closest('ul').find('li').each(function() {
```

$(this) seems to refer to '.swfselector', by using closest, you are searching ancestors.  But UL is not an ancestor of '.swfselector'

EDIT:

Instead of $(this).closest('ul') you should probably do:

```
$('ul').find('li').each(function() {....
```

or even better, give your 'ul' an id

```
$('#myUL').find('li').each(function() {
```

Comment: `$(this).attr("src"` refers to the img tags because it is within the function:  `$(this).find('.tab').each(function() {`
Wouldn't that also refer to the <img> tag? Also I understood an ancestor to be something that comes before it in the DOM no?

Comment: you are correct that $(this) refers to the img element.  but the parent is the 'a' element, the closest would search UP.  UL is a sibling of a parent, and therefore would not be searched. the next in order would be the parent of 'a' which your html doesn't show.

Comment: Ok that makes some sense, so if I put each of these blocks inside a div and then searched parent for .tab I should find the li's?

Comment: i think you just need to call list directly. i have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks the problem is there are many of these blocks on the page and each one must be individual, so if swf selector is hovered in one it only affects the list directly above it.

Comment: ok, now i understand your previous comment.  yes, if you wrapped all this in a div, then searched for that like: $(this).closest('div.container).find('ul')...  then i think that will work.

Comment: Cheers i'll give it a whirl and get back here asap with my results.

Comment: I tried this:   `$(this).closest('div').find('ul')(function() {
     alert(this);
    var className = 'n' + nameString;
       $(this).find('li').removeClass(className).addClass(className + 'o');
    })` but it just changes the image values. For example 1o.png

Comment: you are going to have to give a more unique reference to the containing div.  something like closest('div.container') and the html would be like <div class="container">...

Comment: Hmmm it's still behaving in the same way when I class it like that.